# JMX Monitoring Software

Tags: jboss, monitoring, jmx

I am trying to find a good monitoring software for my simple hello world application written by test purposes.

So far I have tried SCOM 12 and OP5... which I didn't like because I want something more straight forward and easy to configure?

All suggestions are welcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You might have a look at **Jolokia** which is a monitoring solution for accessing JMX MBeans remotely. It ships with an agent which uses JSON over HTTP for its communication in a REST-stylish way.
Have a look at this [Jolokia tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-monitoring/monitor-jboss-as-with-jolokia)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these as well:

- [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
- [AppDynamics](http://info.appdynamics.com/FreeJavaPerformanceDownload.html?c1=GAW_SE_NW&source=USA_app&kw=_PLUS_java_applications_monitoring&cr5=14880621715&cr4=1t3)

Comment: Visual VM provides the better formatted screen for viewing MBeans. all you need to install the plugin and it is available in JDK.

Answer (score 2):

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) offers [JMX monitoring](http://www.nagios.com/solutions/jmx-monitoring). I think the JMX aspect is commercial, built on top of the open-source framework.

See also [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/153252/recommended-jmx-plugin-for-nagios) relating to JMX/Nagios.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see the JMX output, use `jconsole`, it's part of JDK (JDK 7 will require you to install a plugin, but it's all doable from within the app).

If you want a real monitoring app with JMX support, I'd recommend [`Zabbix`](http://www.zabbix.com/).

Comment: i used jconsole , what i want is something works just simply as jconsole does but provides some real monitoring features, i will give Zabbix a try!

Answer (score 0):

Try [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), it is easy to use and gives nice chart views as in jconsole. For monitor MBeans, you have to install a plugin, this is better cause you can have a chart view for int type attribute whichi is refreshed in a configurable polling period. Means you don't need to click on "refresh" all the time!